# React Redux vs fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've been using Redux with React and thunk middleware for some time, and don't get some moments.

1. Is it ok to use plain fetch inside component and save result to local state, when only that component needs this data? What are the drawbacks?
2. Suppose we have a page with *Authors*. User clicks on *Author* and navigates to the page with all the *Books* by this *Author*. Now, users goes back to the *Authors* page and clicks on different one. The data about previous *Author* is still in the Redux store and will be displayed, until new request finishes. How to overcome this?

Comment: 1) yes, it is perfectly ok. As long as only that one component needs the data, it's a very clean way of doing things. However, many Redux purists will say all data should go through redux. At the end of the day there's no difference in performance, just code organization. 2) you need to fire an action to clear out that data when you start loading the new data (or when you stop displaying the other component)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it ok to use plain fetch inside component and save result to local state, when only that component needs this data? What are the drawbacks?

The drawback is that it cannot have benefits of global state, like using Redux dev tools and accessing it when needed, e.g. hydrate it with existing data.

> Suppose we have a page with Authors. User clicks on Author and navigates to the page with all the Books by this Author. Now, users goes back to the Authors page and clicks on different one. The data about previous Author is still in the Redux store and will be displayed, until new request finishes. How to overcome this?

It looks like `Author` should be cleared (e.g. assigned with `null`) on fetch start. A component that depends on data shouldn't be displayed until fetch success.